# How to 'synchronize' master and development branches?

Tags: git

Someone merged our development branch **next** into our **master** branch. Now **next** is one commit *behind* **master**.

Our feature branches come from **next**, and we merge back to **next** from them.

I'm concerned that **next** will diverge from **master** if I merge **feature1** into **next**. There are multiple feature branches.

How do I 'synchronize' **next** and **master**, so that I can merge **feature1** into **next** and 'synchronize' **feature2** to **next** afterwards?

I'm using 'synchronize' to signify *merge*, *rebase*, etc.

UPDATE:

What is confusing me is that **normal** is *behind* **master**. The files are the same. It appears to be a commit created for the pull request merge. My concern is that **next** and **master** will have a mixed divergence

```
master: A <--B
              \
next:   D <--- C
```

A is the merge commit. D is a commit on **next** *after* the merge commit. So, then **master** and **next** have commits not on the other. Does that matter?

Comment: But at some point (release?) you do merge `next` into `master`, right? So all you described is normal workflow? What is the problem then?

Comment: This is slightly unclear to me - what's wrong with merging features into `next`, and then merging `next` into `master` whenever you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *normal* **[git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)**, and is nothing to be worried about.

Feature branches should branch off of `develop` (in your case `next`), and merge into `master` at some point (usually on each new release or version). It's common for `develop` and `master` to diverge; `develop` should almost always be ahead of `master`. You should only ever be pushing to `master` when there's a new release or a hotfix.

Branch your feature branches off of `develop`, and once you are happy with the changes, merge the feature branches back to `develop`. Once you are ready for release, and have ensured that none of the feature branches have conflicts with each other, you can merge `develop` back to `master`. This will bring **all** of the changes from each feature branch into `master`.

Your two branches currently look like the following:

```
next     ------ A -
                    \
master   ------ A -- B
```

As you merge feature branches into `next`:

```
feature2 -----------------
                           \
feature1 --------------     \
                       \     \
next     ------ A -  -- C --- E -- G -
                    \                  \
master   ------ A -- B --- D --- F ---- H
```

Hopefully the above ASCII diagram helps illustrate this, though a number of helpful **picture** diagrams illustrating git flow can be found at **[GitHub](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. Is it normal for **next** to be *behind* **master** after merging *from* **next** *to* **master**? The files are the same. It appears to be a commit created for the pull request merge.

Comment: That's perfectly normal, due to the fact that `master` has to 'combine' its existing code with `develop`, essentially making a new 'commit' to `master`. It's just `master` catching up basically. Assuming all of your files are up the same in both `master` and `next`, you've got nothing to worry about, and the `master` commit should end up in `develop` next time you finish a `hotfix` branch. You can always force `develop` to be up-to-speed by pulling `master` back into `develop` if need be (pulling any extra changes in `master` into `develop`) :)